# What's the best way to strip a href from a fragment of html code?

Tags: c#, html

I have the following fragment of html:

```
<p>​<a href=\"/es-es/Documents/test.txt\"><img class=\"ms-asset-icon ms-rtePosition-4\" src=\"/_layouts/15/images/ictxt.gif\" alt=\"\" />test.txt</a><a href=\"/es-es/Documents/test%20-%20Copy.txt\"><img width=\"16\" height=\"16\" class=\"ms-asset-icon ms-rtePosition-4\" src=\"/_layouts/15/images/ictxt.gif\" alt=\"\" />test - Copy.txt</a><a href=\"/es-es/Documents/test%20-%20Copy%20(2).txt\"><img width=\"16\" height=\"16\" class=\"ms-asset-icon ms-rtePosition-4\" src=\"/_layouts/15/images/ictxt.gif\" alt=\"\" />test - Copy (2).txt</a></p>
```

This html is in a string. I need to strip out the hrefs from all the links and am not sure how to go about this.

**NOTE: I left the string as is that's why its not formatted on multiple lines of code...**

Comment: Define "best".  Easy to implement?  Best run-time performance?

Comment: best overall method, this being good run time performance and easy to implement...

Comment: just `href` or also `src`? HtmlAgilityPack may be the answer you're digging for after all is said and done.

Comment: only the href property is required not src

Comment: I suggest regular expressions

Comment: @DavidThielen: To quote famously: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/93922

Comment: From what ive read its not good to use regular expressions on html any input on that?

Comment: Regex or HtmlAgilityPack are not required you can pretty much manipulate it with XML. Check out my answer

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni For grabbing the href= part, I think it would work fine there. I do agree that for anything more, regular expressions tend to not work well with html.

Comment: "good run time performance and easy to implement" is sometimes like saying "I want a race car that seats 6 and has room for skiis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You could easily achieve the expected result using XML manipulation.

```
string s = "<p>​<a href=\"/es-es/Documents/test.txt\"><img class=\"ms-asset-icon ms-rtePosition-4\" src=\"/_layouts/15/images/ictxt.gif\" alt=\"\" />test.txt</a><a href=\"/es-es/Documents/test%20-%20Copy.txt\"><img width=\"16\" height=\"16\" class=\"ms-asset-icon ms-rtePosition-4\" src=\"/_layouts/15/images/ictxt.gif\" alt=\"\" />test - Copy.txt</a><a href=\"/es-es/Documents/test%20-%20Copy%20(2).txt\"><img width=\"16\" height=\"16\" class=\"ms-asset-icon ms-rtePosition-4\" src=\"/_layouts/15/images/ictxt.gif\" alt=\"\" />test - Copy (2).txt</a></p>";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(s);
            xdoc.Descendants("a")
            .Attributes("href")
            .Remove();
        Console.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString());
```

Comment: Since I wanted to get the hrefs not remove them I used this portion of the code: var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(s).Descendants("a").Attributes("href");

Comment: Since the `img` tags are XHtml this should be fine. If your input can't be guaranteed to be an XHtml fragment, this is not a generalizeable answer as HTML `img` tags aren't self-closed. (Nor many others).

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni Of course, but I concentrated to solve specific problem to OP not a generalized answer which you can use anywhere though it works for well formatted xml

Comment: Of course; I'm mainly concerned in the comments here with those who find the question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

[HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is the most recommended tool to parse and manipulate HTML.

Some starting code would look like following (more samples are one search away):

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlString);  
var aNodesWithHref = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNode("//a[@href]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `AttributeCollection.Remove` method

```
YourLink.Attributes.Remove("href");
```

Comment: That'd be great if it wasn't in a raw string.

Comment: ya, but shouldn't he be required to extract the link and store it in a variable before doing any subsequent steps? i mean, the alternative is to start regexing strings, and we all know how elegant that is...

Answer (score 0):

can you just replace it with Regex?

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, @"<a href[^>]+>", @"");
```